# Econometrics - Granger Causality

Tags: returns, econometrics

Suppose we have two time series, if one has autocorrelations and the other is non stationary how do we test whether they Granger cause a returns series?

Comment: http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html

Comment: Exactly as @John says, the TY test can be done on a VAR in Levels.